# Highlight using facetgrid

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
data = [['yellow', -200,500 ], ['red',501,700], ['blue',701, 900], ['indigo',901,1000], ['black',1001,1200]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Donor', 'Pre_Days','Post_Days'])
```

This is the sample data I am working with and I am trying to highlight the reference data on each grid of the facetgrid plots. Using this syntax

```
g.axes[0].axvspan(-200, 500, color='yellow', alpha=0.5,label="yellow")
g.axes[1].axvspan(501, 700, color='red', alpha=0.5,label="red")
g.axes[2].axvspan(701, 900, color='blue', alpha=0.5,label="blue")  
g.axes[3].axvspan(901, 1000, color='indigo', alpha=0.5,label="indigo") 
g.axes[4].axvspan(1001, 1200, color='black', alpha=0.5,label="black")
```

allows me to manually input the highlight but how could I automatically highlight the plots using the axvspan function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `axs` of the subplots contain a list of objects for each subplot, and if you deal with them in a loop process, you can create a graph with efficient code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,1)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)

for i,ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()):
    ax.axvspan(df.loc[i,'Pre_Days'], df.loc[i,'Post_Days'], color=df.loc[i,'Donor'], alpha=0.5, label=df.loc[i,'Donor'])

plt.show()
```

[image]